# Sending Parse Push with Cloud Code

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I cannot find any documentation on `Parse.Push` used in `Parse Cloud Code`. The usage case that I see is like this...

```
  // Send the push notification to results of the query
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: message
    }
  }).then(function() {
      response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
  }, function(error) {
      response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
  });
```

What I am trying to do is send a push notification if a recipient user is setup for notifications (i.e. has a valid Installation instance, associated to their user).

At the moment I create the query and pass that into the above with pushQuery. What I notice is that a Push is created in the Parse dashboard but the Pushes sent is 0.

Really I just want to create the Push if a user exists. I have created the query and can run this and return if I get results or not like this...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendTurnNotificationToUser", function(request, response) {
  var senderUser = request.user;
  var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
  var message = request.params.message;

  // Validate the message text.
  // For example make sure it is under 140 characters
  if (message.length > 140) {
  // Truncate and add a ...
    message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
  }

  // Send the push.
  // Find devices associated with the recipient user
  var recipientUser = new Parse.User();
  recipientUser.id = recipientUserId;
  var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  pushQuery.equalTo("user", recipientUser);

  pushQuery.find({
    success: function(results) {
      response.success("push user lookup was ok");
      response.success(results);
    },
    error: function() {
      response.error("push user lookup failed");
    }
  });
```

I could add the Parse.Push.send call to the success of the query. However the `Parse.Push.send` has a `where` clause and I do not know what is required there? I do not want to run the query twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be overthinking this. There's no harm in sending a push notification to 0 installations as the push query will not match any recipients. I wouldn't worry too much about this and I wouldn't add such a pre-check to your code. It would add an unnecessary delay to your code and of course would result in the query being run twice.

If you want to do this anyway -- maybe you wish to keep your push logs free of clutter - you can indeed query over the Installation class to check if the query would have matched a set of installations, and if it does, you can then pass that same query to `Parse.Push.send()`.

Yes, that will result in the query run twice, but that's to be expected, as you can't know how many objects will be matched without running the query.

Comment: Hector you are the man! That is exactly what I thought... I guess I didn't want to over clutter the Push information on the dashboard, because a push being sent to 0 people is not a push... its useless data :) I was thinking I might do a query count instead to return slightly faster maybe, then work with the results that way?

Comment: Highly advise against count queries, they won't be faster. Keep in mind that a regular non-push query need only find the first 100 objects that match and it can return early, while a count has to scan the whole table in order to return an accurate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.  Push "advanced targeting" allows the app to push to installations resulting from a query.  That's what the where clause is for...

```
// don't run find on the pushQuery.  set it up as you have it
// then, assuming it returns some installation(s)...

Parse.Push.send({ where: pushQuery, data: "hello" }).then(function(result) {
    response.success(result);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
});
```

Incidentally, you can use `createWithoutData` on Parse.User as a shortcut ...

```
var recipient = Parse.User.createWithoutData(request.params.recipientId);
```

but the longer form you have should work, too.

Comment: Hey Dan. Sorry maybe I wasn't clear I have the parse.push bits working from the first code block

Comment: Oops.. tapped early. The question is that a push is created even if the query results in 0 so I wanted to only create a push if there are results. So I can do the query first and call the push part in success but wouldn't that mean the same query is run twice??

Comment: Undoubtedly, push runs the where query and takes further action (sending a push) only if the query returns installations. I think that's exactly the logic you want.

Comment: Actually a push is created regardless if the installations query returns 0 or > 0.

Comment: By "push is created", do you mean that an installation gets a push even when the query returns no results?  That's a bug, if true.

Comment: No that would be nice ;) No permissions :) I mean a push is created on the Parse dashboard > Push area for API pushes with 0 recipients.

Comment: Oh. I wouldn't worry about that. Consider that to be a report, not a push. That's just a report that no push was sent (as opposed to nothing, which might be interpreted as a failure).